# Setting up a functional model in Keras

Tags: python, keras

I'm just messing around with Keras for fun (continuing education) and am having some issues with specifying the data structure in a CNN.

```
Tutorial: https://github.com/bhaveshoswal/CNN-text-classification-keras
Data: https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/consumer-complaint-database/resource/2f297213-7198-4be1-af1e-2d2623e7f6e9
```

So I have the data processing set up and it looks right.

```
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Embedding, Conv2D, MaxPool2D
from keras.layers import Reshape, Flatten, Dropout, Concatenate
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.models import Model
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from helper_functions import load_data

print('Loading data')
x, y, vocabulary, vocabulary_inv = load_data()

# x.shape -> (50000, 5371)
# y.shape -> (50000, 10)
# len(vocabulary) -> 50111
# len(vocabulary_inv) -> 50111

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split( x, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# X_train.shape -> (40000, 5371)
# y_train.shape -> (40000, 18)
# X_test.shape -> (10000, 5371)
# y_test.shape -> (10000, 18)
```

When I attempt to fit the model, I end up with an error relating to the dimensions of the dataset.

```
sequence_length = x.shape[1] # 56
vocabulary_size = len(vocabulary_inv) # 18765
embedding_dim = 256
filter_sizes = [3,4,5]
num_filters = 512
drop = 0.5

epochs = 100
batch_size = 30

# this returns a tensor
print("Creating Model...")

inputs = Input(shape=(sequence_length,), dtype='int32')
embedding = Embedding(input_dim=vocabulary_size, output_dim=embedding_dim, input_length=sequence_length)(inputs)
reshape = Reshape((sequence_length,embedding_dim,1))(embedding)

conv_0 = Conv2D(num_filters, kernel_size=(filter_sizes[0], embedding_dim), padding='valid', kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu')(reshape)
conv_1 = Conv2D(num_filters, kernel_size=(filter_sizes[1], embedding_dim), padding='valid', kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu')(reshape)
conv_2 = Conv2D(num_filters, kernel_size=(filter_sizes[2], embedding_dim), padding='valid', kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu')(reshape)

maxpool_0 = MaxPool2D(pool_size=(sequence_length - filter_sizes[0] + 1, 1), strides=(1,1), padding='valid')(conv_0)
maxpool_1 = MaxPool2D(pool_size=(sequence_length - filter_sizes[1] + 1, 1), strides=(1,1), padding='valid')(conv_1)
maxpool_2 = MaxPool2D(pool_size=(sequence_length - filter_sizes[2] + 1, 1), strides=(1,1), padding='valid')(conv_2)

concatenated_tensor = Concatenate(axis=1)([maxpool_0, maxpool_1, maxpool_2])
flatten = Flatten()(concatenated_tensor)
dropout = Dropout(drop)(flatten)
output = Dense(units=18, activation='softmax')(dropout)

# this creates a model that includes
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=output)

checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('weights.{epoch:03d}-{val_acc:.4f}.hdf5', monitor='val_acc', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='auto')
adam = Adam(lr=1e-4, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08, decay=0.0)

#model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

print("Traning Model...")
model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs, verbose=1, callbacks=[checkpoint], validation_data=(X_test, y_test))  # starts training
```

Here is the error message:

```
Traning Model...
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-294-835f1e289b39>", line 41, in <module>
    model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs, verbose=1, callbacks=[checkpoint], validation_data=(X_test, y_test))  # starts training

  File "/Users/abrahammathew/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1630, in fit
    batch_size=batch_size)

  File "/Users/abrahammathew/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1480, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='target')

  File "/Users/abrahammathew/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 123, in _standardize_input_data
    str(data_shape))

ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_11 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (18,)
```

Given this error, how should the data dimensions looks like when creating Keras models with the Functional API.

Comment: @DanielMöller the original code doesn't...I guess I should try it with 2, which was the original value

Comment: I think I was mistaken, see @nuric's answer.

Comment: Anyway, 18 is the correct number there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` which expects just the integer labels of classes whereas you give encoded versions already (18,). As such, you need to change `loss='categorical_crossentropy'` to fix the problem.